# Как заставить следующий handler выполняться сразу, после того, как выполнился другой, AIOgram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Хочу зациклить выполнения определённого хэндлера до того момента, пока бы пользователь, посредством нажатия кнопки, сам бы не вышел из этого цикла.

Вот код первого хэндлера:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Testing.easy_difficult_selected)
@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: msg == 'легкий')
async def testing_easy_difficult(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    import random
    data = await state.get_data()
    i = 0
    answers = {}

    kbAnswersChoose = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    category = data.get("category")
    words = await db.async_testing_easy_difficult()
    for word in words:
        answers[i] = word[0][1]
        i += 1
    for button_name, word in answers.items():
        button_name = KeyboardButton(word)
        kbAnswersChoose.insert(button_name)
    btnGoBack = KeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню")
    kbAnswersChoose.insert(btnGoBack)

    word_and_translate = random.choice(words[random.randint(0, 4)])
    word_originally = word_and_translate[0]
    word_translate = word_and_translate[1]

    await state.update_data(word_translate=word_translate)

    await message.answer(f"Дано слово: {word_originally}\n\n Каков его перевод?", reply_markup=kbAnswersChoose)

    await Testing.waiting_for_choose_right_answer.set()
```

Вот код хэндлера, к которому переходит управление, после того, как пользователь отправил слово:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Testing.waiting_for_choose_right_answer)
async def testing_answer(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(answer=message.text)

    data = await state.get_data()

    if data.get('answer') == data.get('word_translate'):
        await message.answer(f"Верно! Это слово переводится, как {data.get('answer')}!")
    else:
        await message.answer(f"К сожалению, ты ошибься. Это слово переводится, как {data.get('word_translate')}. Будь внимательнее в следующий раз!")

    await Testing.easy_difficult_selected.set()
```

Вот мне нужно, чтобы выполнения последнего хэндлера сразу же начал выполняться предыдущий; без отправки сообщения пользователем. Сейчас он начинает работать только в том случае, если пользователь ввёл любое сообщение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте код, отступы разъехались и код перестал быть рабочим

Answer (score 1):

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def first_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # do something

@dp.message_handler()
async def second_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # do something
    await first_handler(message, state)
```

Вы можете вызывать хандлер, как обычную функцию